# Google Sheets query return all rows if they match any value in a column on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with 3 tabs. I want to have tab3 pull all rows from tab1 (southware) into tab3 if there is a match to any value on tab2 (Top)column B

```
=query(southware!B3:AA,"SELECT * WHERE I = '"&Top!B3&"' and D='112'", 0)
```

I can get it to pull all the rows for only 1 cell on tab2- how do I make it evaluate all the values in column B on tab2

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps

```
=query(southware!B3:AA,"SELECT * WHERE I matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Top!B3:B)&"' and D='112'", 0)
```

Comment: OMG- This does it- could you explain how it works, i would love to understand the Where matches statement

Comment: Textjoin creates a regular expression pattern by joining the contents of column B, separated by a 'pipe' (which stands for 'or' in regular expressions). So basically the query string reads "where I matches any of the values in column B."

Answer (score 0):

`QUERY` is not able to work with arrays that's why you will need to use `FILTER`:

```
=FILTER(southware!B3:AA, I3:I = Top!B3:B, 
                         D3:D = "112")
```

but this will may have few limitations, so in such case use this one:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(Top!B3:B, 
 {southware!I3:I, southware!B3:AA},
 {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27}, 0)),
 "where Col3='112'", 0)
```

Comment: First one comes up as Filer Mismatched range, Tried the second one, it works, but only returns one row for each match.