# Query Sheets sum if NOT match any values in this other range

Tags: google-sheets-query

Would like to produce results that are contingent on any of the list of values in one range, not appearing in my other range!

@jpv had a great solution for the OPPOSITE of what i want, in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54763013/12848172

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an example of the data and what the result would look like.

Comment: hey eric -- turns out the issue was more dependent on the underlying data, which is a ticket for another day... (sheets seems to make the assumption that the first value appearing in a cell, should dictate how the rest of the column should be interpreted; if that first value is a text, and you sum the column, you will get the error mentioned in this ticket).

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up hardshell10.